# How could Pharaoh bring sacrifices?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Torah teaches us that Pharaoh brought korbanos (Shemos 14:10)

> ופרעה הקריב
>
> Pharaoh offered sacrifices

It is not clear what sacrifices Pharaoh brought, however the Torah tells us a revealing bit of information about who Pharaoh was (Shemos 32:25):

> כי פרעה אהרון
>
> Pharaoh was Aharon

It would therefore seem that he brought korbanos in the Mishkan, which was where Aharon brought his sacrifices.

However, Pharaoh made himself into a false god (Shemos Rabbah 9:8), and Heaven forfend that we would allow an idol into the Holy of Holies!  How was this allowed?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: _/serious_ Non-Jews are allowed to offer their own Korbanot to our God anywhere and whenever they want.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thus the necessary step of כי פרעה אהרון

Comment: /serious Does that apply if the non-Jew is himself an idol and the sacrifice was therefore originally m'yuchad l'avoda zara?

Answer (score 2):

[Torah Shleima](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_9750_42.pdf) cites a Midrash Aggada that the reason it was OK to make the Cherubs despite the verse of לא תעשה לך כל פסל וכל תמונה - Don't make any graven image - is "לך לא תעשה אבל לי תעשה" - don't make for yourself, but for Me you could make.

It says in the beginning of Beshalach

> ויהי בשלח פרעה
>
> And it was that he sent away Pharaoh

Pharaoh sent himself away, he removed all remnants of self-interest from himself, and it was for Hashem that he made himself into an idol.  That kind of idol is permitted in the Temple.