# Is property belonging to a human god considered tashmishei avoda zara?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, avodah-zarah, korban

If a non-Jew who is worshipped as a god wants to bring a korban, can we accept it? Normally non-Jews can bring any sacrifices to our God which they want and are not limited to the Temple Mount while the altar is standing as we are. The problem is that normally nothing that has been used for another god may be used for sacrificial purposes (or for any other purposes under most circumstances). If this person is worshiped, does this mean he is barred by this halacha from bringing karbanot?

---

Inspired by [this purim torah question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35913/how-could-pharaoh-bring-sacrifices).

Comment: Why limit the question to non-Jews? If a Jew is worshiped can he bring a Korban in the Mikdash?

Comment: Rambam Hilchos aku"m i-think-it's-thirteen says that a Jew's property can only become forbidden by being set aside for a"z if he does it himself.

Comment: @Yitzchak Yayin Nesech?

Comment: What about yayin nesech?

Comment: We accepted from and offered sacrifices for the first few Caesars...Josephus says refusing to offer for Nero was one of the causes of the First Revolt.  Some of the provinces' peoples worshipped the Caesars as gods while they were living, but officially in Rome they were only deified after death by Senate vote(imagine Congress trying to do that!).  I think the only exception was Caligula, who, according to Suetonius, demanded to be addressed and worshiped as Jupiter/Jove during the last couple of years he was alive.

Comment: @Gary do you have an argument for why we excepted those offerings other than the implied "they were the Roman Empire and we were a protectorate"?

Comment: @Yitzchak  I think Josephus says we offered sacrifice twice a day for the Caesars and the "Roman people"...it's in the section where Caligula tries to get his statue put in the Temple and the hubbub that followed...he also has a list of decrees by Julius Caesar concerning the Jews and sacrifices/gifts are mentioned in some of them I believe...Hyrcanus provided help for his army for an Alexandrian conflict and Julius was VERY grateful.  After Rome was actually running things in Judea it WAS probably at least a custom, if not a law, that provincial sacrifices by/for Caesar were made.

Comment: Those are valid historical reasons and I should look them up as I don't know my Josephus anywhere near as well as I'd like but I was asking about theoretical halacha. Suppose instead of Julius Caesar (who was not a god proper when the sacrifices were offered, as you point out) it was my coworker Paul?

Comment: Furthermore, they weren't Caesar's animals being sacrificed.